# Set onClickListener to multiple elements of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a Recycleview with custom items, where if I click on the ImageView of the item it does one thing (changes the image, and selects the item), and if I click anywhere else inside the the item, it does another thing (opens new activity)

Here are my code so far:

item_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Category"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Category"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Category"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Date"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Value"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

listitem_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.inducesmile.androidmusicplayer.view.ItemLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

ItemViewHolder.java

```
    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView category;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView value;
        public ImageView image;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView, ImageView category, TextView title, TextView date, TextView value, ImageView image ) {
            super(itemView);
            this.category = category;
            this.title = title;
            this.date = date;
            this.value = value;
            this.image = image;
        }

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            category = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            value = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Value);
        }
    }

ItemAdapter.java
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ItemObject> allItem;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> allItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allItem = allItem;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_layout, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemObject items = allItem.get(position);
        //set imageview corresponding to category
        switch (items.getItemCategory()){
            case "Other": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_other ); break;
            case "Bills": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bills ); break;
            case "Business": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_business ); break;
            case "Clothes": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clothes ); break;
            case "Commute": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_commute ); break;
            case "Entertainment": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_entertainment ); break;
            case "Food": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_food ); break;
            case "Groceries": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_groceries ); break;
            case "Health": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_health ); break;
            case "Investment": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_investment ); break;
            case "Salary": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_salary ); break;
            case "Travel": holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_travel ); break;
            default: holder.category.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default ); break;
        }
        holder.title.setText(items.getItemTitle());
        holder.date.setText(String.valueOf(items.getItemDate()));
        holder.value.setText( String.valueOf(items.getItemValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allItem.size();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what should I do next, I'd appriciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use setOnClickListeners on your Items within your onBindViewHolder.

Example:

```
holder.title.setOnClickListener( (v) -> { .... });
```

Another way is using a Listener if you want to share the click with your Activity/Fragment.

```
interface ClickListener { void onClick(View view, String data) }; 


new ItemViewHolder ( context, myListener) { ... }
```

after you can use

In your ViewHolder

```
public ItemAdapter (Context context, ClickListener listener, List ....) {
  this.myListener = listener;
}

holder.title.setOnClickListener( v) -> myListener.onClick(view, "whateverdata"));
```

Or you may want to use Android Databinding which reduces your boilerplate.

Comment: Wrong. You can go for it one time in the holder constructor

Comment: yup, sorry. fixed it.of course you need to set the arguments in your adapters constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to approach with it is to implements OnClickListener to your ViewHolder class and set the listener in the public constructor. There is no need to assign the listener in the onBindViewHolder that is called multiple times during runtime. Even if you need to enable disable at runtime in certain conditions, you could add an if/else inside the listener to prevent the action.

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ImageView category;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView date;
    public TextView value;
    public ImageView image;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        category = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        value = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Value);

        // Set the listener to your involved views I.E
        category.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do your things
        switch(v.getId) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `holder.image.setOnClickListener()` in the end of `onBindViewHolder()` method in your adapter.